# Does a grandson saying kaddish for a grandparent where there are no sons take on other responsibilities

Tags: kaddish, sitting-shiva

I will soon be faced with saying kaddish for a grandparent (grandparents only had daughters; father and uncles not able/willing to take on this responsibility).  What other responsibilities will fall to me?  Do I "sit" during shiva?  Forego shaving? Avoid public celebrations?  My thanks for guidance.

Comment: Marc, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and may your next visit be on a happier occasion! Regarding what you personally should do, I recommend that you [consult your rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146), as Mi Yodeya [doesn't offer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734/2) personal rabbinic advice. If you'd like to [edit] this question so that it's more general, for information purposes, it might provide information that'll prove useful in discussion with your rabbi. May your family be comforted among the mourners of Zion and Jerusalem.